# Frank W. Jandl Engineer

Tags: usa, trademark

I'm trying to find out about patents involving my Father, Frank William Jandl. He is long deceased, and I'm his daughter and I'm doing the family genealogy hoping to include information on my Father. He was a mechanical engineer mostly based in the Los Angeles CA area during the years 1945-1980. 
I'd appreciate any and all information!
Thank You,
Camilla

Answer (score 2):

Camila, doing an inventor search on the USPTO website, I found Frank W. Jandl listed as a co-inventor on US Patent No. 4,110,977.

You can download a copy of the patent in PDF form [here](http://free.patentfetcher.com/Patent-Fetcher.php?submit=Fetch&PN=4110977).